# Porque no me toma los assets de mi master blade?

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

Buenas estoy utilizando las datatables de jquery que contiene un searchbar unos filtros y paginacion, por alguna razón me anda en todas las vistas menos en una que es de contactos y no se porque.

master.blade.php:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
@include('backend.layouts.head')
</head>
<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini bg-white">
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- Navbar -->
  <nav class="main-header navbar navbar-expand border-0 navbar-white text-dark">
    <!-- Left navbar links -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" data-widget="pushmenu" href="#" role="button"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
      </li>
 
    </ul>

    <!-- Right navbar links -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <!-- Dropdown Menu -->
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
          <span>{{ Auth::user()->name }}</span>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg dropdown-menu-right">
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a href="{{ route('users.view') }}" class="dropdown-item dropdown-footer">Usuarios</a>
          <a href="{{ route('profiles.view') }}" class="dropdown-item dropdown-footer">Mi Perfil</a>
          <a href="{{ route('profiles.password.view') }}" class="dropdown-item dropdown-footer">Cambiar Contraseña</a>
          <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();"
          class="dropdown-item dropdown-footer">Salir</a>
          <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
            @csrf
        </form>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- /.navbar -->

  <!-- Main Sidebar Container -->
<aside class="main-sidebar py-2" style="  background-image: linear-gradient(200deg, #070525d3 1%, rgba(1, 0, 5, 0.932)100%);">
<!-- Brand Logo -->
<div>
<a href="{{ route('home') }}" class="brand-link text-white">
  <img src="{{ url('backend/dist/img/axis.jpg') }}"
       alt="Axis Logo"
       class="brand-image img-circle mt-1"
       style="margin-left:30%">
  <span class="brand-text font-weight-lighter" style="font-size: 1.3em"> AXIS</span>
</a>
</div>

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="sidebar mt-3">

    @include('backend.layouts.sidebar')
    </div>
    <!-- /.sidebar -->
  </aside> 
@yield('content')</div>
<!-- ./wrapper -->


<!-- Scripts -->

<script src="{{ asset('backend/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('backend/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js') }}"></script>
<script>
$.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button)
</script>
<script src="{{ asset('backend/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('backend/plugins/chart.js/Chart.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('backend/plugins/sparklines/sparkline.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('backend/plugins/jqvmap/jquery.vmap.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('backend/plugins/jquery-knob/jquery.knob.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('backend/plugins/moment/moment.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('backend/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('backend/plugins/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('backend/plugins/summernote/summernote-bs4.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('backend/plugins/overlayScrollbars/js/jquery.overlayScrollbars.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('backend/dist/js/adminlte.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('backend/dist/js/pages/dashboard.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('backend/dist/js/demo.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('backend/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('backend/plugins/datatables-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('backend/plugins/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('backend/plugins/jquery-validation/additional-methods.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('backend/dist/js/handlebars.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/toastr.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('backend/plugins/select2/js/select2.full.min.js') }}"></script>

<script>
  $(function () {
    $("#example1").DataTable();
    $('#example2').DataTable({
      "paging": true,
      "serverSide": true,
      "lengthChange": false,
      "searching": false,
      "ordering": true,
      "info": true,
      "autoWidth": false,
    });
  });
</script>




<!-- Delete Sweet Alert -->
<script>
  $(function(){
    $(document).on('click','#delete',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr("href");
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'Seguro?',
      text: "Se eliminara para siempre!",
      icon: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#070525ce',
      cancelButtonColor: '',
      confirmButtonText: 'Si, eliminar!'
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.value) {
        window.location.href = link; 
        Swal.fire(
          'Listo!',
          'El registro se elimino correctamente.',
          'success'
        )
      }
    })
  });
});
</script>
<!-- Approval Sweet Alert -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $(document).on('click','#approve',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr("href");
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'Estas seguro?',
      text: "Aprobar",
      icon: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#070525ce',
      cancelButtonColor: '',
      confirmButtonText: 'Si, aprobar'
    }).then(result) => {
      if (result.value) {
        window.location.href = link;
        Swal.fire(
          'Aprobado',
          'Operacion aprobada'
        )
      }
    })
  });
});
</script>

<!--Image -->
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#image').change(function(e){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e){
      $('#showImage').attr('src',e.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files['0']);
  });
});
</script>
<!--Select 2 -->
<script>
$(function(){
  $('.select2').select2();
})
</script>

@if(Session::has('success'))
<script>
toastr.success('Actualizado')
</script> 
@endif

@if(Session::has('error'))
<script>
toastr.error('Error')
</script>
@endif
</body>
</html>
```

contacts.blade.php:

```
  @extends('backend.layouts.master')
@section('content')
  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper bg-white">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <div class="content-header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-2">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
    
          </div><!-- /.col -->
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
              <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{ route('home') }}">Home</a></li>
              <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Contactos</li>
            </ol>
          </div><!-- /.col -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.content-header -->

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Main row -->
        <div class="row">
          <!-- Left col -->
          <section class="col-md-12">
            <!-- Custom tabs (Charts with tabs)-->
            <div class="card" style="background-image: linear-gradient(200deg, #070525ce 1%, rgb(1, 0, 5)100%);">
              <div class="card-header">
                 <h3 class="font-weight-light text-white">Contactos
                     <a class="btn bg-white float-right btn-sm" href="{{ route('contacts.add') }}"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle mr-2"></i> Agregar Contacto</a>
                 </h3>
                </div>
              </div><!-- /.card-header -->
              <div class="card-body">
                <table id="example1" class="table table-striped table-responsive" style="width: 100%">
                    <thead class="thead" style="font-size: 14px">
                        <tr>
                            <th style="display:none ">Codigo</th>
                            
                            <th>Nombre</th>
                            <th>Apellido</th>
                            <th>Cuenta a la que pertenece</th>
                            <th>idOwner</th>
                            <th>Puesto</th>
                            <th>Telefono</th>                            
                            <th>Email</th>
                            

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    @foreach($allData as $key => $contact)
                    @if($contact->status ==1)
                        <tr>
                            <td style="display: none;">{{$key+1}}</td>
                            <td>{{$contact->name }}</td>
                            <td>{{$contact->lastname }}</td>
                            <td>{{$contact['holding']['name']}}</td>
                            <td>{{$contact->idOwner }}</td>
                            <td>{{$contact->position }}</td>
                            <td>{{$contact->mobile_no}}</td>
                            <td>{{$contact->email}}</td>                            
                            

                            
                            <td>
                              <a title="Edit" class="btn btn-sm bg-gradient-yellow"  href=""><i
                                class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                                <a title="Edit" class="btn btn-sm text-white" style="background-image: linear-gradient(200deg, #070525ce 1%, rgb(1, 0, 5)100%);" href="{{ route('contacts.edit', $contact->id) }}"><i
                                class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                                <a title="Delete" id="delete" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="{{ route('contacts.delete', $contact->id) }}"><i
                                    class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    @endif
                    @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
              </div><!-- /.card-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.card -->
          </section>
          <!-- right col -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row (main row) -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->     
@endsection
```

Pido disculpas que tuve que adjuntar toda la vista porque nose donde puede llegar a estar el error, las clases estan bien, y la manera de incluir la vista master parece estar bien.